# Is there a way to make a program run throughout time lighter

Tags: python, schedule

I need to run a python program from 7 am to 5 pm but these lines make the program really heavy. This is my code

```
while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
```

I know that I can add time.sleep() but is there a different and more effective way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html maybe?

Comment: cron jobs maybe?